# AngularJS: need a best practice for hierarchical data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular, watched a number of videos and read docs, but not sure for i have it all compiled in my mind. I've seen a bunch of small simple pieces of code but never saw something complex. Do you know of docs/tutorials/examples to help me implement the following?

I want to make a SPA forum web application. The forum consists of numerous topic groups, each of which has topics inside, and each topic has multiple comments.
So this is a hierarchy of nested entities like this: `Forum` -> `Topic Group` -> `Topic` -> `Comment`.
In my SPA I'll need to CRUD any of them or load from server either a single entity (say Comment) or a complex view (a topic with all comments) depending on what user/admin wants.

I can't find an example dealing with the complex hierarchies. Should their controllers and models be nested or separated? How should I separate their CRUD methods? Do I put them all into the top level of $scope? How do I separate parent/child entities of the same $scope that are used in different controllers? What is the better way to substitute View and Edit templates for data being edited by user? Etc...

Or better, is there a sample for the task like mine?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I avoid nesting controllers (making controllers depends on scope of their parent controllers), and instead make custom services through which controllers communicate.

Routing of controllers was the biggest issue for me. I've initially started by using `ngInclude` and handling routing manually, because AngularJS doesn't allow multiple `ngView`s. Solution was [Angular UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). They have [a simple example that can give you an idea on how to structure your navigation](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/).

Basic principle is:

- Any view can have sub view (and it's controller therefore contains sub-controller)
- Controllers in hierarchy don't communicate directly through their `$scope`s. Rather they should use services or events (`$scope.$emit`, `$scope.$on`)
- Any level of depth can be routed to (e.g. `http://myforum.com/#/help-category/how-do-i/msg1`)

Take my view with a grain of salt because I'm fairly new to Angular.

---

Since you're interested in scope inheritance here's an example, but this is discouraged for communication between controllers.

When a controller has a parent controller, then it's scope has a parent scope:

Parent controller:

```
$scope.Breakfast = 'eggs';
alert($scope.Breakfast); // Shows eggs
```

Child controller:

```
alert($scope.Breakfast); // Shows eggs, inherited value
$scope.Breakfast = 'muesli';
alert($scope.Breakfast); // Shows muesli, new value
```

Parent controller:

```
alert($scope.Breakfast); // Shows eggs, value remained same
$scope.Breakfast = 'burek'; // Child doesn't see this change anymore
```

You can get [better description and illustrations in Angulars developer guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

Comment: The $scope is common for all controllers, isn't it? I can access it from any controller

Comment: Each controller get's new `$scope`. If a controller has a parent controller, it's scope knows about parent scope. Child scope inherits parents properties. If child scope modifies inherited property, this property gets "disconnected" (parent keeps original value, child gets new value and they are no longer in sync).

Comment: @NikolaRadosavljević actually when you have inherited property on some child scope which is of type object and you modify it, the value of course stays the same, because the reference stored on parent scope does not change and child still has no property of it's own. It is basic javascript prototype inheritance. Don't confuse it by not very precise explanation.

Comment: @Capaj, that has nothing to do with type of inheritance. If you change a property of a scope, they are disconnected. In your example, you are changing property of an object inside a scope, or "property of a property". In this case you haven't changed property of a scope, and they it won't get disconnected between scope. I didn't realize that this was unclear.

Comment: @NikolaRadosavljević well i think that the type of ihneritance has everything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

One quick note: don't forget that angular is all about your custom directives, so ideally your html for topic template should look like this:

```
<div ng-controller="TopicCtrl">
    <comment ng-repeat="comment in topic.comments"></comment>
</div>
```

Angular really allows to write code unbeliavably DRY, so don't be afraid of directives, they will help you with achitecturing your application structure very much.